# detect broken packages

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management

There are many pages on the web regarding "how to fix broken packages" but I can not find a command to find/detect/view the broken packages. I want to search for orphan packages such as `lib*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sudo apt-get -f install
```

Have you tried this?